# Match negative/positive float/int regex - is it evil?

Tags: regex, floating-point, integer, numbers

I have this regex to test if the user input is valid:

```
value.length === 0 ||
value === '-' ||
(!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/.test(value))
```

The main point is in the regex: `/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/`. However sonarcloud is feeling it as a security hotspot saying:

*Make sure the regex used here, which is vulnerable to super-linear runtime due to backtracking, cannot lead to denial of service.*

I guess it's because of the double digit test, but I couldn't find a way to avoid it. Is it a security threat, or harmless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is caused by the optional `.` between two groups of digits. This could mean that a regex engine would backtrack to match fewer digits with `\d+` and more with `\d*`, but always coming to the same conclusion: it doesn't match.

You can avoid this as follows:

```
^-?\d+(\.\d*)?$
```

This way the only time the `\d*` pattern comes into play, is when there is a separating dot. This means there is no possibility for the same input character to be considered for the `\d+` pattern, and later (after backtracking) for the `\d*` pattern.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.. I was going into crazy directions like if else `^-?\d+\.?(?(?=\.)\d...` things.